# Error: GraphQL Error (Code: 401): {"response":{"error":"Unauthorized","status":401

Tags: jss, graphql, nextjs, sample

I was installing sitecore jss wioth next js and added language en-US.

for deploying app, I ran - `jss deploy items --language=en-US --includeContent --includeDictionary`

[image]

[image]

any ideas to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems due `SITECORE_API_KEY` environment variable in the `(.env or .env.local)` file is not updated with proper Edge token or sitecore api key,
Please update and give a try.

Thanks